# Including OAuth in PHP stops OAuth separate Class from working

Tags: oauth, google-analytics, php, google-ads-api

I am working with Google Analytics and Google Adwords, and I've installed the OAuth "pecl" package to get the Google Adwords working and now my Analytics code doesn't work.

When I open up my php.ini file and comment out (and restart apache)

```
extension=oauth.so
```

The analytics example code works (I adapted it from the OAuth playground that google has open sourced). Is there any way that I could keep my example code from working? I have found that the script crashes on this line:

```
require_once('common.inc.php');
```

Common.inc.php looks like this:

```
<?php
/* Copyright (c) 2009 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 *
 * Author: Eric Bidelman <e.bidelman@google.com>
 */

$PRIV_KEY_FILE = '/path/to/your/rsa_private_key.pem';

// OAuth library - http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/php/
require_once('OAuth.php');

// Google's accepted signature methods
$hmac_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();
$rsa_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_RSA_SHA1();
$SIG_METHODS = array($rsa_method->get_name() => $rsa_method,
                     $hmac_method->get_name() => $hmac_method);

/**
 * Makes an HTTP request to the specified URL
 *
 * @param string $http_method The HTTP method (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE)
 * @param string $url Full URL of the resource to access
 * @param array $extraHeaders (optional) Additional headers to include in each
 *     request. Elements are header/value pair strings ('Host: example.com')
 * @param string $postData (optional) POST/PUT request body
 * @param bool $returnResponseHeaders True if resp. headers should be returned.
 * @return string Response body from the server
 */
function send_signed_request($http_method, $url, $extraHeaders=null,
                             $postData=null, $returnResponseHeaders=true) {
  $curl = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

  // Return request headers in the reponse
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

  // Return response headers ni the response?
  if ($returnResponseHeaders) {
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  }

  $headers = array();
  //$headers[] = 'GData-Version: 2.0';  // use GData v2 by default
  if (is_array($extraHeaders)) {
    $headers = array_merge($headers, $extraHeaders);
  }

  // Setup default curl options for each type of HTTP request.
  // This is also a great place to add additional headers for each request.
  switch($http_method) {
    case 'GET':
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
      break;
    case 'POST':
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
      break;
    case 'PUT':
      $headers[] = 'If-Match: *';
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $http_method);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
      break;
    case 'DELETE':
      $headers[] = 'If-Match: *';
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $http_method);
      break;
    default:
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  }

  // Execute the request.  If an error occures, fill the response body with it.
  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  if (!$response) {
    $response = curl_error($curl);
  }

  // Add server's response headers to our response body
  $response = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) . $response;

  curl_close($curl);

  return $response;
}

/**
* Takes XML as a string and returns it nicely indented
*
* @param string $xml The xml to beautify
* @param boolean $html_output True if returned XML should be escaped for HTML.
* @return string The beautified xml
*/
function xml_pretty_printer($xml, $html_output=false) {
  $xml_obj = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
  $level = 2;

  // Get an array containing each XML element
  $xml = explode("\n", preg_replace('/>\s*</', ">\n<", $xml_obj->asXML()));

  // Hold current indentation level
  $indent = 0;

  $pretty = array();

  // Shift off opening XML tag if present
  if (count($xml) && preg_match('/^<\?\s*xml/', $xml[0])) {
    $pretty[] = array_shift($xml);
  }

  foreach ($xml as $el) {
    if (preg_match('/^<([\w])+[^>\/]*>$/U', $el)) {
      // opening tag, increase indent
      $pretty[] = str_repeat(' ', $indent) . $el;
      $indent += $level;
    } else {
      if (preg_match('/^<\/.+>$/', $el)) {
        $indent -= $level;  // closing tag, decrease indent
      }
      if ($indent < 0) {
        $indent += $level;
      }
      $pretty[] = str_repeat(' ', $indent) . $el;
    }
  }

  $xml = implode("\n", $pretty);
  return $html_output ? htmlentities($xml) : $xml;
}

/**
 * Joins key/value pairs by $inner_glue and each pair together by $outer_glue.
 *
 * Example: implode_assoc('=', '&', array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2)) === 'a=1&b=2'
 *
 * @param string $inner_glue What to implode each key/value pair with
 * @param string $outer_glue What to impode each key/value string subset with
 * @param array $array Associative array of query parameters
 * @return string Urlencoded string of query parameters
 */
function implode_assoc($inner_glue, $outer_glue, $array) {
  $output = array();
  foreach($array as $key => $item) {
    $output[] = $key . $inner_glue . urlencode($item);
  }
  return implode($outer_glue, $output);
}

/**
 * Explodes a string of key/value url parameters into an associative array.
 * This method performs the compliment operations of implode_assoc().
 *
 * Example: explode_assoc('=', '&', 'a=1&b=2') === array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2)
 *
 * @param string $inner_glue What each key/value pair is joined with
 * @param string $outer_glue What each set of key/value pairs is joined with.
 * @param array $array Associative array of query parameters
 * @return array Urlencoded string of query parameters
 */
function explode_assoc($inner_glue, $outer_glue, $params) {
  $tempArr = explode($outer_glue, $params);
  foreach($tempArr as $val) {
    $pos = strpos($val, $inner_glue);
    $key = substr($val, 0, $pos);
    $array2[$key] = substr($val, $pos + 1, strlen($val));
  }
  return $array2;
}

?>
```

I was wondering if anybody had experience with this extension. Perhaps I could rename some of the OAuth classnames? It seems to be that some of these classes are conflicting causing this not to work. I'm going to need to have these scripts working side by side, (ie. under the same php.ini configuration).

Another alternative that I have been wondering about: Is there a way to include an extension in the php.ini file for only one script (Adwords Script)? And then by default not include the extension?

Any advice would help! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got around this by using dl() to dynamically load the extension

http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php